# unable to read lines of log file

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have an AWS S3 bucket with a bunch of log files in them. I have a lambda function using node.js 8.10 runtime that reads each line of the log file. This is what I have:

```
const readline = require('readline');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {

        let bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        let key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

        // documentation for this method:
        // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getObject-property
        let readStream = S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).createReadStream();  // 1

        const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input:  readStream
        }); 

        rl.on('line', async (line) => {
            console.log(line);  
            // process line as needed
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
};
```

In the snippet above I'm printing the line in the log file to the console just for testing, but I don't see any output.

But if I refactor the code like this it works:

```
const stream = require('stream');
const bufferStream = new stream.PassThrough();
const readline = require('readline');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    try {
        // retrieving first record only just for
        // testing
        let bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        let key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

        // data.Body is a Buffer
        let data = await S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).promise();               
        bufferStream.end(data.Body);   // 2

        const rl = readline.createInterface({
                input:  bufferStream
        }); 

        rl.on('line', (line) => {
            console.log(line);
            // process line as needed   
        });

    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
};
```

For the line marked 2, the getObject function returns a buffer and is converted to a stream.

Is it possible to do this without using a buffer? My thinking is if the log file is very large it is inefficient to convert a buffer to a stream. I'm wondering if I can use a stream directly like the line marked 1.

EDIT:
I did some more testing and got it to work but without an async lambda function.  Here it is:

```
exports.handler = function (event, context, callback) {
        // for testing I'm looking at the first record
        let bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
        let key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;

        const readStream = S3.getObject({ Bucket: bucket, Key: key }).createReadStream();

        const rl = readline.createInterface({
            input:  readStream,
            crlfDelay: Infinity
        }); 

        rl.on('line', (line) => {
            console.log(line);

        });
}
```

Does anyone know why this refactored code works, but not with async lambda ?

Comment: So you want to read that log file line by line ?

Comment: Yes.  To give more context, the log files are S3 access logs.  Each line of the log file will be sent to elasticsearch.